# ContextMenu.isOpen is missing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, contextmenu

As you can see below, when I leave my richTextBox1 with the mouse, it should be hidden. Now this workes fine, but when I  right click and open a contextmenu the program also hides, and that's fine, because it should. But I don't want it to so I found this page with MSDN explaining how to use [ContextMenu.isOpen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx) but it doesn't work in Visual studio.

```
 private void richTextBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
```

If it did I would just do it like so:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!richTextBox1.ContextMenu.isOpen()){
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
    }
```

Am I misunderstanding how to use the function, or is it normal for Microsoft to document functions that do not exist?

Can you help me get it working or to do something similar?

Comment: reference missing ... try to chek the reference is missing or not

Comment: `ContextMenu.isOpen()` is for WPF ContextMenu. Are you coding for winforms or WPF?

Comment: How can I find the reference, MSDN says it's part of the. Which should be loaded for me to even use contextmenues.
Namespace:    System.Windows.Controls
Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Comment: I'm coding for winforms.How do you see that it's for WPF?

Comment: Because `PresentationFramework` is an assembly of WPF, and the winforms controls use `System.Windows.Forms`,not `System.Windows.Controls`. And answering your question, no, Microsoft does not _document functions that do not exist_

Comment: Ahh. I'm still very new to this, so I would have never been able to figure out the difference. Do you know of a similar way of doing this for WinForm?

Comment: @SteffenRasmussen see if my answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winforms `ContextMenu` does not have a `isOpen` property. What you can do is subscribe to its `Popup` and `Collapse` events and use a private variable to save the ContextMenu status. Something like this:

First we declare a boolean variable:

```
private bool isContextMenuOpen;
```

Then, in the form's constructor (or after we add the `ContextMenu` to the `RichTextBox`) we subscribe to the events:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Popup event is raised when the contextmenu is shown
    this.richTextBox1.ContextMenu.Popup += ContextMenu_Popup;
    //Collapse event is raised when the contextmenu is hiding
    this.richTextBox1.ContextMenu.Collapse += ContextMenu_Collapse;
}
```

Event Handlers:

```
private void ContextMenu_Collapse(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.isContextMenuOpen = false;
}

private void ContextMenu_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.isContextMenuOpen = true;
}
```

Then, your code would be something like this:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.isContextMenuOpen){
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and see if I can get it running. I'll have to learn how to make extended methods or what it's called. But I need to learn that anyways. I'll get back to you once I've tinkered with it, a bit.

Comment: This works well. The window doesn't close when I mouse over the ContextMenu. The only issue is that no matter where my mouse is when I close the ContextMenu, the window will minimize.

Comment: A few modifications later and it works now. Thank you for the help. And for teaching me a lot about how C# woks.

Comment: Glad it helped. That's why we are here, helping others :)